# Clarification Request for multivariable optimization

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I'm doing some self-study on multivariable optimization for an economics course.

To find a critical point (potential min/max) of a F(x,y), one must find where
aF/ax=0 and aF/ay=0.

Can someone explain (high level only, no rigorous proofs please) why finding where deltaF=(af/ax)+(af/ay)=0 wouldn't work? I think the point where deltaF=0 would be a potential min/max as the output of the function is not going higher or lower?

Thanks! :)

Comment: The expression you're calling $\Delta F$ is not conventionally used, for the reasons given in the answers below.  Are you (mis)copying it from somewhere else or did you invent it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. My textbook says that deltaF=(af/ax)+(af/ay) is how much the function changes if x and y are both marginally changed. I would think, therefore, that the point where deltaF no longer changes would be a potential min/max?

Comment: I suggest you go back and look again, and check if it isn't something like $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \Delta y$.  The extra variables make a big difference.

Comment: Oh you're right! Thank you! Just curious, what would deltaF=(af/ax)+(af/ay) signify, if anything?

Comment: That would be the directional derivative in the direction $\left<1,1\right>$.  The example below has the property that if you increase $x$ and $y$ by the same amount, $F$ doesn't change at all. So this particular directional derivative is zero.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your criterion is that the function does not improve if you move in the direction $(x,y) = (1,1)$, which is much weaker than having a critical point.

You can construct the counterexample $F(x,y) = x-y$. In your notation, $$\Delta F = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 1-1=0$$
so every point would be a stationary point.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My textbook says that deltaF=(af/ax)+(af/ay) is how much the function changes if x and y are both marginally changed. I would think, therefore, that the point where deltaF no longer changes would be a potential min/max?

Comment: @findingmyway Your textbook is not wrong, but does not consider what happens if you only change $x$ while keeping $y$ fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(x,y) = x-y$.  Then the graph of $F$ is a plane and has no max's or min's.  But

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 1-1=0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. My textbook says that deltaF=(af/ax)+(af/ay) is how much the function changes if x and y are both marginally changed. I would think, therefore, that the point where deltaF no longer changes would be a potential min/max?

Comment: It's not that $\Delta F$  doesn't change, it's that the change in the $x$ direction is the opposite of the change in the $y$ direction.   Case 1:  Insist that $a =1$ and $b=0$.   This can be satisfied at only one point in the $ab$=plane $(0,0)$.  Case 2:  Insist that $a+b= 0.$  This is satisfied for an infinite line of points.  It is a much less restrictive condition.